# Apply Robot Framework keyword to column

Tags: python, pandas, robotframework

I have a csv file that I am reading in robot framework. I have developed a keyword that I want to apply to every value in a particular column. The method works using a For loop but it is so time consuming since I have more than 10,000 rows. How can I apply my Robot Framework keyword to a series of values without using a For loop on my column ? I know that the pandas library can be useful to run an `apply` on a column but I don't know how to implement it in Robot Framework.

Comment: I can help you if you only need to work with pandas. I can read csv, process, and save csv.

Comment: if i understood correctly you are trying to achive something like data driven tests. you can look into https://github.com/Snooz82/robotframework-datadriver#example-csv . Or you can use pandas by creating custom keyword in rf.

Comment: Very likely that it is so time consuming because robotframework loops are not very efficient and write a lot to logs. Try to implement it in custom python keyword.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. @JaPyR, you are right. I ended up implementing custom keywords with python and it was much faster than doing loops in Robot Framework.